# RabbitMQ basicGet

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

```
I have been using `basicGet` method of RabbitMQ to fetch messages from MQ.
everything is working as expected. However when multiple instances of `JVM` are running i.e when multiple worker servers are present , the same message is being sent to all the worker servers (JVM).

I have used a "direct" exchange on the `Rabbit MQ configurations`.

**Sample code :**

    basicGet("SampleQueue", true);

Please help.


**Scenario :** I have 4 messages present in the Rabbit MQ. I have two worker servers defined, which when executed should fetch 2 messages each (2 for each worker server). But currently, I am seeing that the two worker servers is fetching all the messages i.e 4 each.
```

I would like to ensure that the messages are being sent to Worker servers in a round robbin manner.

So Ideally, the Rabbit mq should not post duplicate messages to all worker servers.

```
I am using Spring AMQP implementation. The below snippet is being executed in a Spring Job which extends ItemReader. 

**Sample code :**

GetResponse message = ApplicationContextProvider.getChannel().basicGet(
                "SampleQueue", true);

**Here is my Queue configuration :**

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
        host="host" username="guest" password="guest" />
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
    <rabbit:template id="template"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" exchange="Sample" />
```

**The Exchange defined in Rabbit MQ is** :

Type : direct
durable : true 
name : Sample

**The Queue defined in Rabbit MQ :**

name :Sample Queue

**Binding :**

Sample(Exchange) binded to SampleQueue (Queue) with routingKey (Sample).

Thanks.

Comment: after doing `basicGet` you sure you are doing `basicAck`?

Comment: You need to show your code/configuration; what does this question have to do with 'spring-amqp'? You are using the rabbit API directly.

Comment: I am using spring job to read messages from Rabbit MQ

Comment: yes, I am doing basicAck.!!  basicGet("SampleQueue", true); , here the boolean true stands for AutoAck is true .!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [RabbitMQ routing tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html) page I think the *Multiple bindings* section explains what you are experiencing.

**Multiple bindings**

[image]

> It is perfectly legal to bind multiple queues with the same binding
>   key. In our example we       could add a binding between X and Q1 (Q2)
>   with binding key black. In that case, the *direct exchange will behave
>   like fanout* and will broadcast the message to all the matching
>   queues. A message with routing key black will be delivered to both Q1
>   and Q2.

If you would like a round-robin kind of dispatch then each worker should subscribe to the same queue like this

[image]

That is the concept of work queues. The RabbitMQ page has an excellent [tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) about this concept.

But if you would still like to use a direct exchange then each worker would have to bind its own queue to the exchange with a different routing key.

> The routing algorithm behind a direct exchange is simple - a message
>   goes to the queues whose binding key exactly matches the routing key
>   of the message.

[image]

> In this setup, we can see the direct exchange X with two queues bound
>   to it. The first queue is bound with binding key orange, and the
>   second has two bindings, one with binding key black and the other one
>   with green.
>
> In such a setup a message published to the exchange with a routing key
>   orange will be routed to queue Q1. Messages with a routing key of
>   black or green will go to Q2. All other messages will be discarded.

Comment: Are you sending messages that have routingkey='Sample'? How many queues are you creating - one or two?

Comment: No I am sending messages without routing key :     amqpTemplate.send("SampleQueue", message); there is only Queue.

Comment: No I am sending messages without routing key :     amqpTemplate.send("SampleQueue", message); there is only one Queue.The messages are being posted successfully. However when i am listening to messages from queue with the help of worker servers, the same messages are going to all the worker servers. It is not behaving in  a round Robbin manner.

Comment: I dont' see how this can happen unless you are sending duplicate messages to the RabbitMQ or there are indeed 2 queues created. If you only have 1 queue then this shouldn't happen. Or maybe I am missing something fundamental. Check the state with your rabbitmq management plugin.

Comment: hey filip..you are right. I see duplicate messages are going to the queue. Thank you so much.!!